# Asus X455LJ Wifi and Bluetooth not working

Tags: networking, drivers, bluetooth, broadcom

I have an ASUS X455LJ running Ubuntu 16.10 and 3 month ago I successfully installed the WiFi card driver and used the Windows hex Bluetooth driver.

To be able to use the Bluetooth, each time i turn on or restart my PC I need to manually enable the driver with "modeprobe" command.

For the WiFi, it worked for those 3 month but with a resent attempt for an update, the WiFi is not working anymore.

**WiFi information:**

lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01) Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [11ad:6675]

lsmod | grep -e ath9k -e asus

```
asus_nb_wmi            24576  0
asus_wmi               28672  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
asus_wireless          16384  0
wmi                    16384  3 asus_wmi,mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  40960  4 asus_wmi,int3406_thermal,nouveau,i915
```

rfkill list all

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
     Soft blocked: no 
     Hard blocked: no
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
     Soft blocked: no
     Hard blocked: no
2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
     Soft blocked: no
     Hard blocked: no
```

I would like your help with this.

Thanks!